# xpages number converter with combobox in ND9

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I'm having trouble using number conversion with numberConvert in a combo box in xpages on a Domino 9 server. This used to work on the 8.5 server.

When I submit the values I get: Validation Error: Value is not valid

I also tried to populate the values with "new javax.faces.model.SelectItem" but that didn't make any difference.

Does anyone know how to use numbers in combo boxes in ND9?

Here is the source (I removed everything unneccesary for this example):

```
<xp:comboBox id="combo" value="#{viewScope.testfield}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="9" id="selectItem1" itemValue="9">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr=new Array("0","1","2"); return arr;}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:message id="message1" for="combo"></xp:message>

<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:save></xp:save>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

If you want to select numbers in a ComboBox you have to define comboBox's possible values as an array of numbers, not strings.

[image]

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.testfield = 1}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:comboBox id="combo" value="#{testfield}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="0" itemValue="${javascript:0}"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="${javascript:1}"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="${javascript:2}"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:comboBox>
```

This example works perfect **without** using a converter if the value is a scope variable.

If you have a flexible number of entries you can use both ways shown in Adibabu Kancharla's answer.

The number converter is necessary for binding to a document's number field. The following example works for me in ND853 and ND9. I had to add `integerOnly="true"` though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="NumberTest"
            action="editDocument"
            documentId="477FF8697EE50EDBC1257B710073DDE3">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:comboBox id="combo" value="#{document1.Number}">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="0" itemValue="${javascript:0}"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="${javascript:1}"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="${javascript:2}"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:comboBox>
    <xp:message id="message1" for="combo"></xp:message>

    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:save></xp:save>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: You're right. This works works without using a converter. The problem seems to come when I bind the value to an Number field. I could't get it to work, with or without a converter. On 8.5.3 it works fine and the xpage makes documents with number values. I wonder how we get different results?

Comment: You're right, the example does work for scope variable but not for number fields. I added an example for number field binding too.

Comment: Great! Now I got the code working. The difference between 8.5.3 and 9.0 seems to be that integer only has to be selected on 9.0 when the field is bound to a Number field. Thank you very much for your help, Knut!

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that field 'testField' is of type 'Number' on the underlying form.
I had the same issue on 8.5.3 server. So, i wrote the below code to overcome the issue..

```
    <xp:selectItems>
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var arr = ['0','1','2']
var comboOptions = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){   
    comboOptions.push(new javax.faces.model.SelectItem(parseFloat(arr[i]), arr[i]))
}
return comboOptions}]]>
 </xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
```

You can simplify the above code, if you know how to use managed beans.
Below is the code for bean.

```
public class ApplicationSettings implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private List comboOptions;

 public ApplicationSettings(){
  loadDefaults();
 }

 public void loadDefaults(){
  for(int x = 0; x <= 3; x = x+1){
   SelectItem item = new SelectItem(new Double(x),""+x);
   comboOptions.add(item);
  }
 }

 public List getComboOptions() {
  return comboOptions;
 }
 public void setComboOptions(List comboOptions) {
  this.comboOptions = comboOptions;
 }
}
```

In faces-configxml, register the managed bean(name: ApplicationSettings, scope:application).
Then in your xpage..

```
<xp:selectItems value="#{ApplicationSettings.comboOptions}"></xp:selectItems>
```

Comment: This solution works on 8.5.3 if you have the number converter and the type of the field is Number. But when I copy the same code and form to our 9 server I get Validation error: Value is not valid.